# DataTables javascript - RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I do not load the datatable when I change the page but if it does when I refresh it:

When I go to the page for the first time
[image]

When I go to see students
[image]

When he returned to the student page
[image]

My datatable js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#alumnos_table").dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        responsive: true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sSearch": "",
            "sZeroRecords": "No existen datos",
            "sInfo": "Registro _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Registro 0 al 0 de 0 registros",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros)",
            bDestroy: true,
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [7]}
        ],
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/client/alumnos"
    });
});
```

my routes:

```
namespace :client do
    get "index" => "index#index"
    resources :alumnos
    resources :asignaturas
    resources :carreras
  end
```

my action index:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: AlumnosDataTable.new(view_context)}
    end
  end
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `turbolinks` in your application, it might be the reason for it.

Try replacing:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   ....  
   .... 
})
```

With:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  ....
  ....
})
```

or this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the code list above is a typical "Turbolinks" issue, you can either remove the "Turbolinks" from you project or you can load scripts like this

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

});
```

You can see the documentation here [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks).